# Saving accessToken from Facebook, but it resets

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use the C# wrapper for Facebook. If i authenticate the user and obtain the accessToken, I want to store the accessToken so that I can access my own personal Facebook stuff (like photos, etc). However, the accessToken invalidates after a period of time. How can I ensure that it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Access tokens for users can become invalid due to various reasons. In most cases, they can expire if it’s past the **time specified by the ‘expires’ field** (by default access token have a 2 hour lifetime). What many developers do not realize is that an access token can also expire if a **user changes their password**, **logs out** or if she **de-authorizes** the app via the App Dashboard. It is very important that your apps handle such situations. If your access token expires, you need to reacquire a valid access token. [[1](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/)]

Comment: So if I cannot use the offline_access extended permission, how can I add more time to the expiration?

Answer (score 2):

If you request and obtain the offline_access extended permission then you will receive a non-expiring access token.  Even these non-expiring offline access tokens can be invalidated by some of the actions emaillenin describes (password change, app removal/de-auth)

Comment: So using the offline_access extended permission, I should be ok with this token?

Comment: Yes.  Get the other permissions you need as well such as publish_stream

Comment: For clarification to anyone knew to facebook api development, you add 'offline_access' to your scope variable in the url. E.G. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT&scope="offline_access"`

Answer (score 0):

Me I store the Facebook app/user access Token after he authorized my webapp.

Later, when user come back on is account in my WebApp I check if this User access Token in my appDatabase = the accessToken call with php-sdk like so:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($SimpleConnectConfig);    
if ($facebook->getAccessToken() == $databaseFBuserAccessToken){
echo '<a href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl($appArrayPermsScope).'">
Link a Facebook Account
</a>;
}else{
echo '$facebook->api($user.'/permissions','DELETE');';
}
```

de-Identified my Facebook App